# How to evaluate broad-sense heritability of microbiome associated plant genotypes in R

Tags: bioinformatics, microbiome

I have a data containing 196 accessions of *A. thaliana* from which I studied leaf bacterial and fungal community and, therefore, sequenced and found several OTUs. Now, I want to evaluate broad-sense heritability of microbes across accessions of *A. thaliana* in R. Kindly reply and if needed, I'll provide the data table.

Comment: As a disclaimer i don't know how to do this, but a [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heritability/heritability.pdf) exists in R for these calculations. The package contains datasets from Arabidopsis you can use to play around with the functions.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "evaluating the heritability"? Moreover, *how to do something in R* is not really on-topic here. The focus should be on the idea instead of the programming.